# Datagridview formatting my values

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, string-formatting

I have a datagridview.

and this is how i add data on page load

```
    Private Sub GetDataforGrid(ByVal Code As String, ByVal Name As String, ByVal Base As String, ByVal Type As String, ByVal DateMatch As String, ByVal RateMatch As String, ByVal Spread As String)
    dgConfiguredRates.Rows.Add(Code, Name, Base, Type, DateMatch, RateMatch, Spread)
End Sub
```

and here is where i call it with paramaters :

```
GetDataforGrid(lvRates.Items(k).SubItems(0).Text.ToString(), lvRates.Items(k).SubItems(1).Text.ToString(), cbBaseCurrency.Text.Trim, "SP", "Exactly", "Multiply", "0.001")
```

now my problem is that when i try to save my data to the database it says that a string or binary is going to be truncated .

so as i step through the save function i see that the parameter(Spread) i "0.001D" instead of normal 0.001 .

anyone know how i can get this Letter out of the string?

i am using VS2010, VB.net, windwows forms

regards

Comment: check database column DataType Length

Comment: @MandeepSingh the length for the column is decimal(10,8) thanks for quick reply

Comment: provide all column datatype lenght nvarchar and varchar